# Can a SWITCH CASE statement get too big?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a SELECT/SWITCH statement that has continued to grow... I THINK I should be about done.
However, there are currently 19 options... is there something that would be better than this?

Coding in C#

IE:

```
switch (Request["typeOfRequest"].ToString())
        {
            case "comboFills":
                Response.ContentType = "text";
                Response.Write(getVizData());
                break;
            case "linkFormField":
                Response.ContentType = "text";
                Response.Write(getVizRuleFields());
                break;
            case "getDispositions":
```

Comment: It all depends on the context. Is there any way you could restructure your logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch statements can be way larger than that...  However, eventually you may run into efficiency concerns.  I don't think that 19 cases is a problem.  I've had much larger statements.  Usually a switch statement is not a processing bottleneck, so it's the last thing you optimize.

Each case translates onto the CPU as a test and a jump, so think of how many operations your worst case would be and decide whether it's worth fussing over, and how many operations you would actually save (both worst case and average).

Saying that, there's a couple of obvious options.  If you have numeric types and they are evenly distributed, you can split your switch statement into multiple switches....

```
if value < 50
  switch
    ...
  end
else if value < 100
  switch
    ...
  end
else
  ...
end
```

This is of course trickier to maintain, and may rely upon knowledge of constant values that makes your code ugly.  It's really just a grungey search tree...

Another way is to put all your cases into functions, and build a tree or hash table that maps each value to a function handler.  That way you can always rely on O(logN) search times (or better, in the case of hash tables).  I repeat: don't do this unless you have a very good reason to.

Hope that helps give you some insight.  Apologies for not being language-specific.  You didn't mention a language, but I'm assuming it's something like BASIC.

Comment: If it was something like BASIS, you would be coding with 'Select Case'.

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit puzzled because the title says "switch case", and the question body says "select".

Comment: Ahh right, I see you've added code to the question.  I don't know how C# compiles switch statements that have strings.  A large switch with strings is likely to be inefficient.  Saying that, it's conceivable that these *could* be optimized like dictionaries, but probably aren't.  So you might consider a search tree, dictionary, or hash for this...  But when I say 'inefficient', I'm really splitting pre-split hairs...  This looks like a web application, SOAP service or something.  Bottom line: don't worry about it - stick with code clarity.

Comment: Actually, one of the reasons why switch in C++ can only deal with numeric types is that it is not translated into a big if/else chain but it creates lookup tables to jump at places, at least after optimization